# SVN Update Error on Mac OS

Tags: macos, svn

I am trying to update my project in SVN and getting the following error:

"Unable to connect to a repository ar URL ‘svn+ssh://svn.abc.com/svn/Project' To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from ‘ssh’ in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file."

I am using OS X and the configuration file is located at ~/.subversion 
I went to the file and I see all the rows in the config file are commented out !!!

Kindly help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In ~/.subversion/config you probably have the line in the `[tunnels]` section:

```
# ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
```

This is show you what the default is if `ssh` is not defined. After this line add:

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh
```

HTH